# Use of "the" before an error message

Tags: definite-article

I wrote:

> When I try to open an "avi" file, I get an/the exception "Failed initializing decompressor".

Which should I use, **the** or **an**, why?! Do I need other words to relate **exception** and the **exception message**

Comment: 'the' sound better. That's because you are talking of a specific exception and you even 'mention' that exception. So, it's like telling, when I try to close the file, I get **the** message - cannot close the file, it is opened in some other location.

Comment: Both are correct. But the definite article is widely used when mentioing errors. Aside from that, always say "**AVI**" instead of "**avi**". This format (and almost all) are initials. So, whenever referring to any format, always say it in block letters. I didn't edit your post as that was your original sentence! Cheers :) Only say "**avi**" when you are including the full file name. Example: "**HowToDance.avi**"

Comment: @Usernew That's a great piece of Info. +1

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong as such, with either of your options.
Besides you can really make it an adjective, like below.

> When I try to open an 'avi' file, I get the 'Failed initializing decompressor' exception.

Also, avoid using double quotes if it is not direct speech.

Comment: Re double vs single quotes: [there isn't a clear rule](http://www.scribendi.com/advice/when_to_use_double_or_single_quotation_marks.en.html) for when to use one versus the other.

Answer (score 1):

This question is not easy to answer without specific context as using *the* or *a/an* is heavily context-dependent.

For example, if you are talking with someone who is not knowledgeable about the word ***exception*** or the message ***Failed initializing decompressor***, you had better use *an*:

> When I try to open an avi file, I get an exception (which
>   says/reads) "Failed initializing decompressor".

If you are talking with a computer/program expert, you could use *the*.

The most important thing is you can't use *the* ***unless*** the following noun has been mentioned before or is regarded as common knowledge.

Note: The rule about when to use *a/an* and *the* is not that strict in the above examples. However, *the* should be used when a noun after *the* is common knowledge or previously mentioned.

Comment: I asked the question in StackOverFlow.com. you mean if I use "an", "which says/reads" is optional? because I can get using "the" and immediately mentioning the phrase, but this is a bit strange for "an"

Comment: @Ahmad The same rule applies to the word "error". You can use *an* error and *the* error depending on context. An exception is a message, you could use *which says/reads* before the message.